# Populate Form with localStorage Values Using jQuery Attribute Prefix Selector

Tags: jquery, json, forms, attributes, local-storage

I am saving JSON data by stringifying it (them) and using localStorage. I re-create the data as objects and have been trying unsuccessfully to convert the object into values I can populate an HTML form with. The following jQuery snippet iterates over my stored values and outputs precisely what I want in the console:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var test01stuff = $.parseJSON(localStorage.getItem("test01Info"));
                   $.each(test01stuff, function(i,item){
                        $.each(item, function(name,value){
                            console.log(name + ":" + value);
                            $( "id[name|='" + name + "']" ).val( value );
                        });
                    });
    });
```

This absolutely iterates properly on an object like:

```
{
    "test01Info": [
        {
            "test01_Num": "4",
            "test01_Length": "387",
            "test01_Depth": "23"
        }
    ]
}
```

E.g., a name/value pair like `test01_Length:387` comes up fine in the console, as do all my other stored values. But trying to utilize jQuery's attribute prefix selector in the next line to populate my HTML with something as basic as:

```
<form id='test01form'>
  <input type='number' name='testy' id='test01_Length' min='0' max='999' data-role='none'>
</form>
```

fails every time -- the input stays blank, and yet there are no errors thrown in the console. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you trying to use a starts-with attribute selector? Won't `$( "#" + name ).val( value );` suffice? Your current selector is looking for an `id` element (which doesn't make sense) which has a `name` attribute that contains `test01_Length`.

Comment: I cannot speak to the "sense" one attribute makes over another for you, but something like `$( "name[name|='" + name + "']" )` also has the same non-result for a form element with the given name as opposed to id. In many cases, I won't know what will be handed down to me from JSON, but I will know the prefix. In any case, this should work with exact strings, as well, according to jQuery's API documentation: "Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-)."

Comment: `a[b|="c"]` looks for an element in the form; `<a b="d">xxx</a>`, where `d` contains (or is) `c`. A valid use case is `$('input[name|="foo"])`, which will match `<input name="barfoobar" />`. The code in your post will is therefore trying to match something like `<id name="test01_Length" />` (note the `id` element tag).

Comment: ... your HTML has the a `name` attribute with the `testy`, which the `[name|="' + name + '"]` part of your selector (with name = `test01_Length`) won't match. It's your **id** attribute which *is* `test01_Length`, so try `$( "[id|='" + name + "']" ).val( value );` instead.

Comment: I was just noting that it didn't work with the name or id attributes. But _now_ I see where I didn't make sense -- you found exactly what I missed, which was my assigning of value vestigial to my original attempt to use name in the syntax I had. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got to the bottom of it ;).

Answer (score 1):

@Matt actually answered it above, but I can't designate his comment as an answer. I had:

```
$( "id[name|='" + name + "']" ).val( value );
```

when I needed:

```
$( "[id|='" + name + "']" ).val( value );
```